# How can I store images for my react native app?

Tags: react-native, expo, cloud, android-image

I want to build a cloud-based app. for that I used many images but I think that will increase the size of my app, so where can I store my images and get them by URI.

I tried storing and sharing from google photo, but that doesn't work.
so please mention me the way I do that!

Comment: You can use cloudinary. It is free and has really good documentation on how to upload images.

Comment: Have you tried firebase?